# Standalone implementation of asmx web service (server side!) without using IIS (custom web server)

Tags: web-services, ssl, httprequest, httpresponse, httplistener

I have to "publish" certain SOAP/XML functionality via asmx web service by using an WSDL file that I got from a third party. 
That means I have to host a web service, usually this would be done by using IIS as a web server, however I need to create a project that implements its own web server to bypass the need for IIS.

This is part 1 of the problem, part 2 is - running the resulting app on Ubuntu under MONO.

Back to part 1, after having done a few days of research I have found that the following link is practically the only one that has relevant information (as I do not want to use WCF);
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Before I dive in and commit to spending a lot of man hours into this, I would like to know whether the data provided at he above mentioned link is still valid - and whether there are other (superior) options to achieve what I need to achieve.

If someone has already solved this problem ih his/her dev. career - please share your knowledge. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem at the web server: you can create a PHP-based webservice that implements NuSoap.